# Validate a string based on Rules

Tags: algorithm

A string is formed using rules and we need to validate it.

Output: Return True or False

1. Start with empty string “”
2. Take any character and make it a pair “aa”
3. Take any character and add the character at ends “baab”
4. Concatenate any strings formed using the above methods

Input: aa
Output: true

Input: baab
Output: true

Input: edggdefeeddeef
Output: True

I tried to use a counting method (like you use boolean array of all characters to increment and decrement count, when the count is 0 you create a substring of the rest), to the problem in O(n) but the order of the items matter, so it does not work.

I think the only method is to use left and right pointer and keep counting from the left and when you hit the total count as 0 check if it’s a palindrome and then move the window.
The complexity will be O(n^2), you form the window and then check whether it’s a palindrome.

Am I missing anything here?
Any better solution?

Comment: Fail to see how `edggdefeedeef` would return true for the algorithm you describe.

Comment: The definition of the language you're trying to recognize isn't consistent.  For example, rule 2 is useless because you can get the same effect by using 1 followed by 3. Are you giving the exact description from the assignment?

Comment: @Robby sorry it’s supposed to be edggde followed by feeddeef

Comment: @Gene do you have a solution? I remember seeing the question like so

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

Your description makes it sound like the grammar for the language you're trying to recognize is

```
S -> \eps | A S A S
A -> a | b | c | ...
```

In words, this is all strings where pairs of letters enclose only pairs of letters (or nothing at all).

This leads to a nice recursive form. When I see character `c` on the input, I set out to match that `c`. If the next character on the input is `c`, good. I'm done. Otherwise I recursively match that next character and then try again to match `c` with what's left.

In C, this looks like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static bool match(int c) {
  int next = getchar();
  if (next == EOF || next == '\n') return false;
  if (next == c) return true;
  return match(next) && match(c);
}

static bool check(void) {
  int c = getchar();
  if (c == EOF || c == '\n') return true;
  return match(c) && check();
}

int main(void) {
  bool result = check();
  printf("Result: %s\n", result ? "yes" : "no");
  return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is correct.

```
$ echo edggdefeeddeef | ./foo
Result: yes
$ echo edggdefeedeef | ./foo
Result: no
```